# Probability Seating

Tags: probability

A conference room has $m$ men and $w$ women and $m + w$ chairs.

- Two of the men always sit together. Find the probability that all women are adjacent to each other.
- Find the probability that no two women are adjacent to each other

Please be detailed in your answer so I can understand clearly what you're saying.

Comment: I came up with w / (m+w-2) for part a) but not so sure about it as I am getting confused not having factorials as I did with another problem where I found the probability of all women sitting adjacent in which the solution was [(m+1)!w!]/(m+w)!.

Comment: Is it around a round table? Or are the chairs lined up in a row?  Note that at least when $m\approx w$ your suggested number is implausibly large.

Comment: There is no indication if they are in a row or round table.

Comment: Perhaps there are chairs around three sides of a table and one or more separate rows of chairs along the walls. I have been in conference rooms like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the absence of information, I assume that seats are arranged in rows (or in a $\bigcap$ which amounts to the same thing).

---

**Part 1**

There are 3 groups: 2 men as one clump, $m-2$ individual men, and $w$ women as another clump. i.e. $(1+ m-2 +1) = m$ entities, and permute each clump among its members.

Thus

$$\text{Favorable Ways} = (1+m-2+1)!\cdot2!\cdot w! = 2!\cdot m!\cdot w!$$

and

$$Pr = \dfrac{2!\cdot m!\cdot w!}{(m+w)!}$$

---

**Part 2**

$$\_m\_ m\_ m\_\ \dots\dots\ \_m\_ m\_ m\_$$

There are $m+1$ gaps between men (including ends) where women can be accommodated, and assuming that $w \le m+1$,

$$\text{Favorable Ways} = {m+1\choose w}\cdot w!\cdot m!$$

and

$$Pr = \dfrac{{m+1\choose w}\cdot w!\cdot m!}{(w+m)!}$$

Comment: Where do you get (1 + m - 2 + 1)! from?

Comment: 1 clump of two men, *m-2* other men, 1 clump of *w* women

Comment: Why do two of the groups correspond to 1, while the m-2 men give m-2? Should it not be 3!?

Comment: An extra term inadvertently crept in. I have edited Part 1. As for *m-1* men, they are not a clump, they are individuals, so have to be treated as such.

Comment: Thank you - this is the type of method I am familiar with

Comment: I was thinking, and am not sure, about the total possible ways to seat on Part 1.  Will it still be (w+m)! if it is given that two of the men always sit together before finding the probability that the women are all adjacent?

Comment: The denominator gives *unrestricted* arrangements which will always be $(w+m)!$

Comment: You are welcome !

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a conference room, I am going to presume that people are seated in a circle, or that nobody has only one person next to them.

So we can say that without any constraints, there are $(m + w - 1)!$ ways to place everyone, since we have to place one person, and then everyone else relative to them. If the table wasn't a circle, it would be the regular $(m + w)!$

If we go in one direction, say left to right, Then A sits next to his friend B  $\frac{1}{m + w - 1}$ or 1 out of all the possible people are the case we want. The same if we go from right to left, giving a final chance of $\frac{2}{m + w - 1}$

Another solution is to treat the two buddies as one, and sit them down, then we have $(m + w - 2)!$ ways to sit everyone else, and $2!$ ways of sitting the friends. So the number of cases where it happens out of all the possible cases is $$\frac{2!(m + w - 2)!}{(m + w - 1)!}$$

$$= \frac{2!(m + w - 2)!}{(m + w - 1)(m + w - 2)!} $$

$$= \frac{2}{m + w - 1} $$

---

This one is a bit trickier. We have to presume that m >= w

If we let all the guys sit down first, we have $(m-1)!$ ways of doing that, and they can leave $m$ possible gaps for the women to sit in.

Now the problem is how many ways can the gaps be filled? It is $${{n} \choose {k} }= \frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$$

$${{m} \choose {w} }= \frac{m!}{(m-w)!}$$

Multiplying both parts together we get

$$\frac{m!(m - 1)!}{(m-w)!}$$ ways out of $(m + w - 1)!$

$$= \frac{\frac{m!(m - 1)!}{(m-w)!}}{(m + w - 1)!}$$

$$= \frac{m!(m-1)!}{(m-w)!(m + w -1)!}$$