# Simplify $\frac{a!}{(a+b)!}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factorial

Is there a way to simplfy $\frac{a!}{(a+b)!}$?

What about $\frac{a!b!}{(a+b)!}$?

I have tried taking ${a}$ out of the top and bottom, getting $\frac{(a-1)!}{(a+b-1)!}$ but I can't reduce it down to remove $a$ completely.

Comment: You cannot get $\frac{(a-1)!}{(a+b-1)!}$ by "taking $a$ out of the top and bottom." Why not write out the _complete_ expression (without any !) for the case $a=3, b=2$ and see if you can figure out where you went wrong?

Comment: @DilipSarwate I see, I can take a out of the top, but only a+b out of the bottom

Comment: Alas, you are _still_ missing the point. There _is_ an $a$ in the denominator of $\frac{a!}{(a+b)!}$ that can be canceled with the $a$ in the numerator, but while this leaves $(a-1)!$ in the numerator, you don't have $(a+b-1)!$ in the denominator any more.

Comment: @DilipSarwate yes, I can either choose to take a from the top to get $(a-1)!$ or $(a+b)$ from the bottom, and get $(a+b-1)!$ doing so doesn't achieve anything useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write it explicitly and then simplify as follows :
$$\frac{a!}{(a+b)!}=\frac{1}{(a+1)(a+2)\ldots (a+b)}$$

The same works for $\frac{a!b!}{(a+b)!}$ .

Also (maybe it helps you) :

$$\frac{a!b!}{(a+b)!}=\frac{1}{\binom{a+b}{a}}$$ where :

$\binom{n}{m}$ is a binomial coefficient and represents the numbers of ways $m$ objects can be chosen from $n$ objects and is generally given by the formula :

$$\binom{n}{m}=\frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!}$$

I don't think there's more to simplifying these expressions than this .

Maybe you can show us a problem where you tried to use this simplification . This way we can all better know how to help you .

Comment: $\frac{m!(m-1)!}{(m-w)!(m + w -1)!}$

From a question I answered on seating probability

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1423714/201158 This is the link if you are interested

Comment: That's not much you can do about this expression to simplify it.You can however reduce it in terms of binomial coefficients : $$\frac{\binom{m}{w}}{\binom{m+w-1}{w}}$$

Comment: damn, thanks anyway